# Spring Integration DSL HTTPRequest

Tags: httprequest, spring-integration, dsl

We are evaluating Spring Integration DSL , and came up with a POC where we are sending a HTTP Post request to a Message channe also we have created a PollableChannel to receive.

We started testing with Jmeter by sending concurrent requests but for some reason 
the thread which sent http request is receiving response for different thread request.

I tried searching google to find a similar kind of work to get some idea, but no luck.Even Spring Integration DSL does not have any examples on this.

Can anyone guide me through this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you elaborate? add your code snippet for the integration DSL based component, and JMeter config?

Comment: Really, please, share the configuration and some test-case on the matter to reproduce it from the Framework perspective. Or from other side to help you to overcome the issue if something is wrong on your side.

Comment: Frankly speaking am not sure which part of code I have to provide. But, one question raises me is will the Spring Integration internally takes care of correlating the request and response where the message which was sent to channel is set with a correlationId.